# Error compiling honeyd in Debian

Tags: config, honeypot, libnet

I am trying to install honeyd. the configuration was successfull but the `$ make` gives me these errors.

I have added `/etc/ld.config.so` to the `/usr/local/lib`, I have tried everything but the error still exists.

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:855: recipe for target 'honeyd' failed
make[2]: *** [honeyd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/marion/Desktop/Tools/Honeyd-honeyd-1.6.7'
Makefile:1244: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/marion/Desktop/Tools/Honeyd-honeyd-1.6.7'
Makefile:700: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```